# CORS error while requesting file using signed URL (AWS)

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have applied Cloudfront function to decode application token for restrict user wise access content. so I have sending `Authorization` token on each header for security.

```
let signedUrl = cloudfrontSigner.getSignedUrl({
    url: fileUrl,
    dateLessThan: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60),
    privateKey: awsPrivateKey,
    keyPairId: keyPairId,
  });
```

I am able to access file content in Postman with pass header token but could't access using Angular request and showing a CORS error. I allowed CORS from bucket setting using below code still getting an error.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://*",
            "https://*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Angular code:

```
public downloadFile(downloadLink: string) {
      return this.http.get(downloadLink)
        .map((response) => {
           const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'text/csv'})
           window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))
      });
}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: getting CORS error 'Cross origin resource sharing preflight missing allow origin header'

Comment: Whether AWS supports patterns like `https://*` is unclear to me. Try `*` instead.

Comment: tried already  thanks